# getting an error when trying to create IAM user with administrator access

Tags: amazon-web-services

so I just received my AWS educate account few days back and I am trying to create an IAM[image: error-image] user with Administrator access. i have attached the Administrator access policy but I am getting this error while creating an IAM user. I have attached the screenshot of the error in the images. It would be really nice, if somebody could look into this issue and help me fix it.

Comment: As you've assumed a role, that role does not have permission to add those permissions to a user. If the role is part of an organisation an SCP may be specifically prohibiting these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, AWS Educate Starter Accounts **are very limited**. This includes almost any operation on IAM.

Their [FAQ](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf) clearly writes:

> You can create users, but **cannot associate login profile** or **access keys** for them. *Additional restrictions may apply

A solution is to change your account into standalone/full account. This way they can provide you with credit that you can use on your account and you will have full permissions. May also try contacting their support. Maybe they can relax some restrictions for you.

Otherwise, have to use the account within its limits.

Comment: yes! you are right, aws educate starter account is very restricted.

Comment: @habiba thanks. hopefully you manage to use it for other things they all:-)